# Access dom element with reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an AntD component, and i don't have access to the html markup to use `useRef` to apply a style to next class , depending by a condition:

```js
span.ant-descriptions-item-content
```

This is why i used:

```js
if(my condition) {
  document.querySelector('span.ant-descriptions-item-content').style.background="red"
}
```

**demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-ant-design-demo-fdwxd?file=/index.js

It is ok to use native ways of accessing dom element like `document.querySelector`, or exists another method to do this in my case?

Comment: Direct DOM manipulation is an anti-pattern in React. React has ways to access DOMNodes, set style, attributes, etc...

Comment: @Drew Reese, could you show please how to access that selector?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code?

Comment: @DrewReese, demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-ant-design-demo-fdwxd?file=/index.js Please, tell me if the code works

Comment: Technically, *yes*, but definitely not recommended. I'd say using a query selector to target a DOMNode is only really useful as a last resort. (Think escape hatch). Antd appears to lock their UI elements down a lot (makes sense as they appear to be very opinionated), versus other component libraries that expose out available classnames as part of a component's props API to allow for customization. Antd is so wound tight I could only get CSS and `className` working. [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-ant-design-demo-cssclassname-style-x1chm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: The other option I wanted to suggest is theming libraries, like `styled-components`, but unfortunately I was unable to get that working with Antd components. I'm sure I'm simply overlooking something though. Point is there are other options available.

Answer (score -3):

It is generally not recommended to mix different tools that handle changing how the web page is rendering. This can cause unpredictable behavior and components not updating correctly. If you want to change the appearance of a component using React you should be rendering that component within React.

Comment: in your opinion, i can't access that selector in react?